# Accessing the kmem_cache structure after creating the cache

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

`struct kmem_cache *kmem_cache_create` *returns a ptr to the cache on success*, it seems like it returns a pointer to the structure `kmem_cache`. I want to access that structure, the structure can be found in [`mm/slab.h`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/mm/slab.h#L20), and as you can see there is an item of type `unsigned int` called `size`.

```c
#include <linux/slab.h>

struct kmem_cache *kmem_cache_sys;

static int __init sys_module_init(void)
{
    kmem_cache_sys = kmem_cache_create("cache", 4000, 0, SLAB_HWCACHE_ALIGN, NULL);
    pr_info("%d\n", kmem_cache_sys->size);
    // ..
}
```

**`invalid use of undefined type ‘struct kmem_cache’`**

Comment: *found in mm/slab.h*. And where in your code do you include that header?

Comment: @kaylum You can't. I think `linux/slab.h` includes that header by default.

Comment: Have you actually checked? I don't think it does include that. And that's likely your answer - the structure is intended to be opaque and the authors don't want you accessing the internal sttcutures.

Comment: @kaylum `authors don't want you accessing the internal sttcutures`, I don't think so, that structure includes some useful information about the `cache` we create.

Comment: Just because you think it is useful doesn't mean the authors agree with you. This is just standard  information hiding. It is clearly intended to be an opaque structure where the fields cannot be accessed directly. The authors provide accessor functions such as `kmem_cache_size` to access specific fields that they allow (that's just an example and doesn't get the field you want).

Comment: If you really want to access that then you need to make the full `struct kmem_cache` definition available in this file by somehow including `mm/slab.h` (though that is likely going to cause compile errors) or you have to manually duplicate the definition in this file. But note that both these ways should only be used for testing and not production code as the authors can change any internal structures at any time as it is not part of the public API.